# I would like to create a database containing 600 text files for an android Application

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-intent, android-listview

I have 600+ text files. How do I put them in a database, with mySQL lite. 
I want to have 3 columns: index(1 to 600), title and content. 
How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

When you create the database (the single table in it), the index should be auto-generated when the entry is created in the table (if you properly created the table with auto indexing)

I would use TEXT (varchar) for the title & blob for the actual text file (the data in it).

The previous answer seems to put you on the right track, though I'm not sure I quite understand how you intend to actually populate the table with the data.

Comment: oh, okay, so I don't need to worry about the index then. Thanks for the pointer about the storage types. I don't really understand either how i'd do it. I mean, I can't copy and paste 600 files haha

Comment: If you are creating the database in your project (meaning before compiling & publishing the app & that you have the database file in your project hierarchy) you could always make a small tool that reads your file, connects to the db & enters the data for you in the db. ex: (for each file in the directory, insert into table title (file name), content (content of the file)

Comment: also, for that automatic indexing, it's done when you define the structure of the table (when you create it)

Comment: Oh wow! This is what I was looking for. I was crushing my head trying to figure out how I'd connect the DB with the raw files. I guess I just need to get that thing working. Thank you so much for your help. I'll try your method.

Answer (score 0):

- Use content provider for android below is nice link.
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html.
- For datatype to use integer,text,text as columns, below is
  datatype link of sqlite.
- http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
- But Instead of storing the file data in sqlite, I would suggest you to store sdcard path of files in sqlite table and retreive from sdcard when required.
- In above case columns will be index,title,filepath.

Comment: Thank you. The first link seems to be dead though.